# Canvas with animated SVG pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, canvas

I am trying to create a canvas with symmetrical arranged dots that fadein/fadeout individual (like a pulse effect).

What I've got so far:

```
var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext("2d");

ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
var total_circles = 50,
    posTop = 10,
    posLeft = 10;

for(i = 0; i < total_circles; i++){
    posTop = posTop + 10,
    posLeft = posLeft + 10;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(posLeft, posTop, 3, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
    ctx.closePath();
    ctx.fill();
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0tLxanws/

I don't even get the points arranged (first step, then animating).

I created a small image so you can see what I mean:
[image]

Also a small jsfiddle with the effect but not with a canvas:
http://jsfiddle.net/dx3jgy8h/

Comment: Are you saying that you want an effect like an optical illusion.?

Comment: well, not really - what i actually want is that all circle have an opacity of 0.3 or something and some of then fadein/fade out, more like spangled sky

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/0tLxanws/1/

Comment: yeah thats pretty cool. now how can i animate (fadein/out) random circles in a loop (like stars shining in :D )

Comment: i builded the effect I try to achieve here: http://jsfiddle.net/dx3jgy8h/ - the thing is, that this takes a lot performance and i think building it with a canvas would be better...